# How to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at the point $(-2,0)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Could someone please demonstrate this problem? I can't seem to get it right.

Find $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ at the point $(-2,0)$, if $y^3 = x^3 + e^x \sin y +8$.

Comment: ...one thing FOR THIS SPECIFIC PROBLEM... once you have differentiated with respect to $x$ you may at that point substitute $x=-2$ and $y=0$. It is not necessary to solve for $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}=f'(x,y)$ --- although it is best practise if you want to ask more questions about the implicitly defined curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implicitly differentiate the function:

$$\begin{align} y^3 = x^3 + e^x \sin y +8 & \iff y^3 - x^3 - e^x\sin y + 8 = 0\\ \\ &\implies 3y^2\dfrac{dy}{dx} - 3x^2 - e^x\sin y - e^x\cos y \frac{dy}{dx} = 0\\ \\ 
& \iff \dfrac{dy}{dx}(3y^2 - e^x\cos y) = 3x^2 + e^x\sin y\\ \\ 
& \iff\frac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{3x^2+ e^x \sin y}{3y^2- e^x \cos y}
 \end{align}$$

Now, substitute $x = -2$, $y = 0$ to find the value of $dy/dx$ at $(-2, 0)$, and you'll have $$\frac{dy}{dx}(-2, 0) =\frac{3(-2)^2+e^{-2}\sin 0}{3(0)^2-e^{-2}\cos 0}
= \bf -12e^2$$

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
y^3 = x^3 + e^x \sin y +8
$$
then
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\left[y^3\right]&=\frac{d}{dx}\left[x^3 + e^x \sin y +8\right]\\
3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}&=3x^2+e^x\sin y+e^x\cos y\frac{dy}{dx}\\
3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}-e^x\cos y\frac{dy}{dx}&=3x^2+e^x\sin y\\
\left(3y^2-e^x\cos y\right)\frac{dy}{dx}&=3x^2+e^x\sin y\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{3x^2+e^x\sin y}{3y^2-e^x\cos y}\\
\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{x=-2,\ y=0}&=\left.\frac{3x^2+e^x\sin y}{3y^2-e^x\cos y}\right|_{x=-2,\ y=0}\\
&=\frac{3(-2)^2+e^{-2}\sin 0}{3(0)^2-e^{-2}\cos 0}\\
&=\large\color{blue}{-12e^2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate both sides of the equation wrt $x$.

Note: $\underbrace{\frac{d}{dx}[f(y)]=\frac{df}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}}_{\text{chain rule}}$.

Doing this, we have:
$$3y^2\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2+\underbrace{[e^x\sin(y)\frac{dy}{dx}]+[\sin(y)e^x]}_{\text{using the product rule and chain rule}}.$$

Now I'll leave it up to you to re-arrange this equation to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ (Hint: put all the $\frac{dy}{dx}$s on one side and factorise!).

When you've got $\frac{dy}{dx}$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, all you need to do then is substitute $x=-2,  y=0$.